# How to make a torus progressively thinner/smaller (not larger) using an array modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, procedural

I've managed to do an approximation of the opposite of what I want:

[image]

By pairing an empty to the object offset in the array modifier of a torus, and scaling the empty.

[image]

However, what I'd like to do is something like this (preferably parametrically/procedurally/non-destructively):

(However in this image, this is non-procedural/destructive):
[image]

(Cross section view):
[image]

And have multiple parameters that allow me to control:

1. Distance between toruses
2. Rate at which they get smaller

Put another way, see this image:

[image]

1. For every new torus:
2. Scale the magenta circle slightly larger
3. Scale the red circle slightly smaller

Comment: I don’t understand. Why is the one labeled as the center torus bigger, and are we looking at the side of some thing that’s actually vertically arranged?

Comment: You do know you can give something a scale factor of 0.5 on all three axes, right?

Comment: @TheLabCat Sorry I should've made that clear, the illustration is a cross section (if I understand correctly), as though slicing the toruses with a knife in the center.

Comment: @TheLabCat I'm not sure what you mean by giving a scale factor of 0.5 on all three axes (or I think I understand you but just not sure what you're trying to say). If you scale the empty both above 1 and below 1, you get the same (or similar) shape as above where the torus thickness gets larger as you go to the outer rings.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the inner torus to have a smaller major radius (thus of course being inside the other toruses), but a larger minor radius, resulting in an overall lumpy cone profile of the toruses combined.

Comment: I guess to put it more precisely, this image is helpful: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Torus_cycles.svg - Here's what I want: for every new torus, scale the magenta circle up slightly (see image), and scale the red circle down slightly. (Edited my answer with this too since it's clearer I think)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Array and Spin.**

[image]

- Add a circle, edit it such that center is outside.
- Add an empty give it uniform scale between 0 and 1
- Add an array modifier to circle, empty as object offset, and either a relative or constant offset to space them
- Add a screw modifier to revolve the circles into torii.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I can scale the circle to control the rate of scaling, and I can control the distance between the torii via the relative offset.

Comment: Transforming  the empty makes for some cool effects too.